# How can I calculate mouse specific movement with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, mouse

I want to know how can I calculate a mouse specific movement.

I want to have some advices how to determine the mouse is moved from A to B.

For example, like win8. When the mouse is on side of window, then drop it down, a sidebar will appear.

```
$(window).on('mousemove' function(e){
   if(e.pageX is on area of or close to the side of window){
      // how can I calculate if the mouse Y is from a point to a point??
      if(Y is moved from A to B){
          //do something
      }
   }
})
```

Comment: The problem you face is that it will be very rare for the user to move the mouse from exactly one pair of co-ordinates to exactly another pair.

Comment: @BenM I dont very understand. But I think I only need to know is how to determine the X or Y is changed in a direction...., amt I right?...

Comment: Assuming particular swiping motion in certain region of screen, surely just calculate gradient by storing last location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine the left hand side of the `window` simply by checking its width:

```
if(e.pageX >= ($(window).width() - 20))
```

Will check if the mouse is within 20px of the right-hand side of the window.

To check how far it's moved, you'll need to record the last known position somehow, and then compare it. So for example you might do something like this:

```
var last_pos = { x: false, y: false },
 coord_check = $(window).width() - 20; // or whatever value from the right you want to check.

$(window).on('mousemove' function(e) {

    if(e.pageX >= coord_check)
    {
        // If they're null, we can't do anything:
        if((last_pos.x !== false && last_pos.y !== false) && ((e.pageX - last_pos.x) > 20)) {
            // you can access the current position through e.pageX and e.pageY
            // last_post.x and last_pos.y will tell you the last known position
        }
    }

    // Now we need to update the last position:
    last_pos.x = e.pageX;
    last_pos.y = e.pageY;

});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I think I got some ideas. However, the method now storing last position will actually occur every 0.1 sec when you move mouse. The calculation inside of the handler will only determine the gap between 0.1 sec ago....., am I right?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/ ; as I can see, mousemove will response every mouse move. e.pageX - last_positoin_x will actually less than 1??

Answer (score 1):

You should have "regions" to control, and in your mousemove keep track of the last and current region,
and based on the register event handlers to deal with the scenarios, for example from A to B, from C to X ,and  so on. :)

here a task list :

- create array of regions objects with x,y,width,height and name
- in onmouse move check the current region if its different from current, then set the previous with the current and, change the current to current region name.
- set the variable event to previous + '-' + current
- check in your array of event handlers for any data in the event position, if there are any functions there call then

hope it helps !

Comment: Thank you very much. If I store data into array on every mousemove, I already have some idea. So is that the actually way the others are doing? My concern is will doing this affect a lot of performance?

Comment: You're not interested in anything other than the last known position. Storing everything to an array is not necessary.